# Can't run npm run build on ubuntu server on digital ocean

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, npm, webpack, babeljs

On my ubuntu server, as user 'user', I ran npm install, and then ran npm run build.

The following error I got was

```
sh: 1: better-npm-run: not found
```

After I install better-npm with `npm i better-npm-run`. I get the following output, below. Although I'm confused why I needed to do that in the first place, since it's in my package.json and I ran `npm install` already.

```
running better-npm-run in /home/user/website-prod
Executing script: build

to be executed: webpack --verbose --colors --display-error-details --config webpack/prod.config.js 
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './babel-transpiled-modules/plugin/plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user/website-prod/node_modules/webpack-isomorphic-tools/plugin.js:1:80)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

Meanwhile, if I'm ssh'd in as root to the server, npm run build works perfectly fine. No need to run `npm i better-npm-run`. I have a suspicion i'm running into an error regarding being a non-root user and not being able to access the node_modules installed from `npm install`.

If anyone can help me that would be great!

Comment: does it work when you `./node_modules/.bin/better-npm-run` ?

Comment: hmmm... can't seem to find it in the .bin folder in node_modules local to my app

Comment: Did you run `npm i better-npm-run` in `/home/user/website-prod` (where there should be a `package.json` ? (don't run it in root)

Comment: I just did again, and it's not there. There are other packages, but not better-npm-run